# Want to put a button on a sharepoint page to sign document. I don't want users to go to the library

Tags: sharepoint, docusignapi

Just downloaded the docusign app for Sharepoint online. It's on an HR publishing site and the page is for all new hire documentation. I want to put a button on the page to associate with the specific document that needs to be signed. I don't want users to have to go into the library and use the docusign tab. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload an image somewhere of what you want to achieve? You will only be able to add a link to it but one of us will embed it for you. It isn't clear exactly what you want. Are you saying that you have a page that lists all new hire documents and you want a sign button against each?

Comment: Wow! Quick response! I want the functionality of this https://plus.google.com/photos/108300924374556245639/albums/6024824914052743617/6024824917763231922?utm_source=chrome_ntp_icon&utm_medium=chrome_app&utm_campaign=chrome&pid=6024824917763231922&oid=108300924374556245639

To be here:

https://plus.google.com/photos/108300924374556245639/albums/6024824914052743617/6024825024015742818?utm_source=chrome_ntp_icon&utm_medium=chrome_app&utm_campaign=chrome&pid=6024825024015742818&oid=108300924374556245639

Comment: Well crap...I'll have to figure something out

Comment: snag.gy not working. Try these:

The functionality of this button:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t1.0-9/10412030_882655008418525_5817082477059095528_n.jpg

To This Icon:

https://scontent-a-sea.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t1.0-9/10475711_882655381751821_864153766775681428_n.jpg

I made those public so you should be able to see them

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't the Docusign button only work on selected documents in the list? What is under that button - is it JavaScript or a REST URL? Also, am I right in saying that the 2nd image is just a customised list view?

Comment: Yes, the docusign button only works on one selected document. I am only going to have one document template per library (as per HR's request). I have no idea what's under it. The second pic is just an icon. On the two preceding it I just have them linked to a form.

Comment: Edit: the second pic are just jpg images that link to a form.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite see how this will work.

The ribbon command will have some code behind it. Presumably it uses the Docusign API so if you can find the code, you will be able to see what to do. Or review the API docs.

On your page, you would need to trigger the same code on each icon but I assume that the icon already triggers an action (e.g. downloading the file or something), so you would likely need a second icon or link to trigger the docusign action instead.

Not trivial. And I couldn't find another similar issue on Google.

Comment: Well thanks for looking into it. I'll just have to have them go to the library I guess. Thanks again.

Comment: But do add your own answer when you find it. Interesting, wish I could have helped further.